# Trying to Minimize the following function but getting "scalar-valued" error

Tags: function-construction, mathematical-optimization, warning-messages

I have a setting where I have written down an obj function as follows:

```
c := {1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100}; 
n := 6;
alfa := {0.4, 0.35, .15, 0.05, 0.04, 0.01}
objFunc[d_] := 
   ETBasicBPH3[K1, K2, mu1, mu2s, mu2n, mu2f, p, lam, Total[alfa[[1 ;; d]]]] 
     Total[c[[1 ;; d]]] +  
   ETBPH3[K2, mu1, mu2s, mu2n, mu2f, p, lam, Total[alfa[[d ;; n]]]] 
     Total[c[[d ;; n]]]
```

Please note that `ETBasicBPH3` and `ETBPH3` are other functions I defined earlier, I don't think they are relevant to the problem. However, I will show them below.

When I run the following minimization

```
Minimize[{objFunc[d], 0 < d < 6}, d, Integers]
```

I get the following error message, which basically says I should have a scalar valued function

[image: Error message]

Just to note again when I run the function with a single variable I receive no errors; Following piece of code works perfectly fine:

```
 Table[objFunc[d], {d, 5}]
```

> ```
> {1485.34, 1065.14, 1752.46, 1838.64, 2041.65}
> ```

I don't know what exactly causing the problem, any help would be appreciated. Also, any comments about the code itself is also appreciated.

P.S. Here is the functions I mentioned earlier:

[image: Other Functions]

Comment: Would you post your "p.s." code as text rather than an image so it can be easily copied?

Comment: The argument `d` of  `objFunc` is implicitly assumed to be a positive integer  by using it, e.g., in `Total[alfa[[1 ;; d]]]`. `Minimize` simply cannot cope with that. You have to formulate your problem in a different way, e.g., by using `Piecewise`. Moreover, you frequently use `:=` (`SetDelayed`) instead of `=` (`Set`) for setting variables. That's _Pascal_ and not _Mathematica_. (For defining functions, this is okay, though). I'd like to encourage you to read the documentation pages for `SetDelayed` and `Set`, first.